# Can't send data to firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to send data from a contact form to my database using firebase and I tried different ways yet they all failed. Here's my code:

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">First & Last Name</label>
  <input name="name" required [(ngModel)]="nameValue" type="name" class="form-control"
    id="exampleFormControlInput1">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
  <input name="email" required [(ngModel)]="emailValue" type="email" class="form-control"
    id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <textarea name="message" required [(ngModel)]="messageValue" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1"
    rows="3" placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
  <button class="btn " type="submit" (click)="open()" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">SEND</button>
</div>
```

And here's the ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { NgModule } from "@angular/core";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { NgbModal } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { ModalContactFormComponent } from "../../components/modal-contact-form/modal-contact- 
 form.component";

@Component({
  selector: "app-contactform",
  templateUrl: "./contactform.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./contactform.component.scss"]
})
export class ContactformComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   // nameValue = "";
   // emailValue = "";
  // messageValue = "";

  // name: Observable<any[]>;
 // email: Observable<any[]>;
// message: Observable<any[]>;
 data: {
 name: "";
 email: "";
 message: "";
};
constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, private modalService: NgbModal) {}

// onSubmit() {
//   this.db.collection("Messages").add({
//     name: this.nameValue,
//     email: this.emailValue,
//     message: this.messageValue
//   });
//   this.nameValue = "";
//   this.emailValue = "";
//   this.messageValue = "";
// }
onSubmit() {
 this.db.collection("Contact Messages").add({
   name: this.data.name,
   email: this.data.email,
   message: this.data.message
 });
}
       ngOnInit() {}

      ngAfterViewInit(): void {}

   open() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ModalContactFormComponent);
  }
}
```

I have been stuck on this for three days. Originally it came from a project I made a few months ago and I checked it so many times that everything was exactly the same. Apart from the name of the collection and data content, it's a perfect match. The app module file as well. I'm really out of options.  Thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: What is the actual issue? Is there an error in angular? Won't `onSubmit` get called? Or firebase throw an error?

Comment: it won't send the data to the collection I'm trying to create "Messages" or "Contact Messages"

Answer (score 0):

You are not pointing the variables that you are using in the form as the model value

```
 export class ContactformComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
   nameValue = "";
   emailValue = "";
   messageValue = "";

// data: {
// name: "";
// email: "";
// message: ""
// };
constructor(public db: AngularFirestore, private modalService: NgbModal) {}


onSubmit() {
 this.db.collection("Contact Messages").add({
   name: this.nameValue,
   email: this.emailValue,
   message: this.messageValue
 });
}
```

Try using the second onsubmit you have not commented and rename the values from the the proper model of the form

Comment: Do I need to use them? It was on one of the attempts I made but didn't work. Now I tried ass you said, using the second onSubmit and I ket the variable data but still nothing. I'm so sorry... I don't think I understand fully what you're saying... thanks so much for your help Hitesh

Comment: Here as per the html file [(ngModel)]="emailValue"  you have to get the value from these ngModel but you are using data use the this.emailValue so that you can get the user entered value

Comment: ok. Does this mean I have to remove the ngModel: emailValue from the html? Sorry if it seems like a silly question, I'm a total beginner :)

Comment: No don't it is perfect in html you have to get the values from there only in ts using the this.emailValue

Comment: Ok let's break down the problem what it is not sending are the values going  empty is the problem or something else please elaborate on it and make edit into the question

Comment: I actually don't know if the issue is the code something missing, or values as you said. I have no clue :(

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out so just in case someone has the same issue here's my code (with simple validation)

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from "@angular/core";
import * as firebase from "firebase";
import { AngularFirestore } from "@angular/fire/firestore";
import { Validators, FormControl, FormBuilder } from "@angular/forms";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { NgbModal } from "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap";
import { ModalContactFormComponent } from "../../components/modal-contact- 
form/modal-contact-form.component";

@Component({
  selector: "app-contactform",
  templateUrl: "./contactform.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./contactform.component.scss"]
})
export class ContactformComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  contactForm = this.fb.group({
    name: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)]],
    email: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    message: ["", [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]]
  });

  constructor(
    public db: AngularFirestore,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) {}

  onSubmit() {
    console.warn(this.contactForm.value);

    this.db.collection("Contact Messages").add({
      name: this.contactForm.value.name,
      email: this.contactForm.value.email,
      message: this.contactForm.value.message
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {}

  open() {
    this.modalService.open(ModalContactFormComponent);
  }
}




 <form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">First & Last Name</label>
  <input formControlName="name" class="form-control" 
 id="exampleFormControlInput1">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
  <input formControlName="email" class="form-control" 
  id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="name@example.com">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <textarea formControlName="message" class="form-control" 
   id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"
    placeholder="Type message here"></textarea>
   </div>
   <div class="text-center">
  <!-- <button class="btn " type="submit" (click)="open()" data-toggle="modal" 
  data-target="#exampleModal">SEND</button> -->
  <button class="btn " type="submit" [disabled]="!contactForm.valid" data- 
   toggle="modal"
    data-target="#exampleModal">SEND</button>
   </div>
 </form>
```